# remove bundle product with quantity 0 from the cart

Tags: magento2

i have a problem in the development of a store and i need help, in the image below on the bundle products page when resetting the quantity of a product it keeps showing up as 1 in the cart. I need that when resetting the input it just stops showing up in the cart. How is it possible to do this?

[image]

The previous image is of a bundle product, when I leave the input with zero I want it not to appear in the cart.